# Playwright test failure in headless mode

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I have a `beforeAll` function that performs the login in the application I am testing in every `test.describe`. When I am in `headless: false` mode, everything works perfectly. This is the `beforeAll` and the login function:

```
//before alll function
test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await performAutomaticLogin(page);
});

//login function (necessary code for this question)
export const performAutomaticLogin = async (page: Page) => {
    await page.goto('/login');
    await page.click('text=Log in with Google account');
    await page.fill('id=identifierId', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_USER!);
    ...
};
```

However, when I swich to headless mode, I begin to have failures in this line:

```
await page.fill('id=identifierId', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_USER!);

page.fill: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "id=identifierId"
============================================================
```

I have no idea why. I followed this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/3130) but the configuration recommended there did not work for me. This is my configuration:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    workers: 1,
    testDir: '../',
    use: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'Chrome / Edge - FullHD',
            use: {
                browserName: 'chromium',
                headless: true,
                viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
                //these launch options came from github. I tried with and without them
                launchOptions: {
                    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    reporter: [['junit', { outputFile: 'test-results.xml' }]],
};
export default config;
```

Versions:

- playwright/ @playwright/test: ^1.25.0
- chromium version: 105.0.5195.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google OAuth page is different when accessing it in headless mode. You can notice it by taking a screenshot of the page with `page.screenshot()` or by checking the page URL with `page.url()`.

This is how I do it in my project:

```js
async signIn(emailAddress, password) {
    // Make sure we are prompted to sign in with Google
    expect(this.page.url()).toMatch(new RegExp('https://accounts.google.com/(signin|o/oauth2|ServiceLogin)'))

    if (this.page.url().match(new RegExp('https://accounts.google.com/(signin|o/oauth2)'))) {
        // Email address
        await this.page.fill('input[type="email"]', emailAddress)
        await this.page.click('#identifierNext')

        // Password
        await this.page.fill('input[type="password"]', password)
        await this.page.click('#passwordNext')
    } else {
        /* Google uses legacy OAuth page when browser is in headless mode */

        // Fill email address
        await this.page.fill('//html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div/div/input[1]', emailAddress)
        await this.page.click('//html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/input')

        // Fill password
        await this.page.fill('//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/span/div/div[2]/input', password)
        await this.page.click('//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/span/div/input[2]')
    }
}
```

It's not an efficient solution, but works for several months now.

Answer (score 2):

Just add 'headless=chrome' in launchOptions

```
use:{launchOptions: {args: ['--headless=chrome']}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('id=yourId');
await page.fill('id=yourId', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_USER!);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try headed mode. `yarn playwright test --headed` or you can also configure that in your code.

```
import { test, expect, devices } from "@playwright/test";

const deviceUA = devices["Desktop Chrome"].userAgent;

test.describe("Test case", () => {
  test.use({ userAgent: deviceUA });

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await performAutomaticLogin(page);
  });

  test("Test case", async ({
    page,
  }) => {
     ...
  });
});
```

You are telling Playwright to use headed chrome in for this "Test case" where as it is using headless mode by default.